# Add controls link to view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to add controls link to each value in my table. I've created resource controller an now want to call some operations in my view(update,show,delete).
I did it like this:

```
@foreach($teams as $team)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$team->name}}</td>
            <td>{{$team->score}}</td>
            <td>
                <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ route("teams.show/{$team}") }} ">Show</a>
                <a class="btn btn-danger" href="{{ route("teams.destroy/{$team}") }}">Delete</a>
                <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ route("teams.edit/{$team}") }}">Update</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
```

and in my route web file:

```
Route::resource('teams','TeamController');
```

But now I have error when try to access index view:

```
(2/2) ErrorException
Route [teams.destroy/{"id":8,"name":"Zorya","score":15}] not defined. (View: H:\xampp\htdocs\hockeyapp\resources\views\teams\index.blade.php)
```

Comment: `{{ route("teams.show/{$team->id}") }}` I believe you should echo team ID? Not the whole `$team` object.

Comment: in laravel 5 resource controllercreated with functions(destroy,show,update) with argument Team $team and I want deal with it.

Comment: If you say so. But I'm sure that's not how it works.

Comment: it doens't work,that's why I created this question:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is not correct. It should be:

```
<a class="btn btn-info" href="{{route('teams.show', $team->id)}} ">Show</a>
<a class="btn btn-info" href="{{route('teams.edit', $team->id)}} ">Show</a>
```

And destroy route won't work with a href.